# Presenting fields in class diagram

Tags: language-agnostic, uml, class-diagram

```
class A
{};

class B
{
    A a;
};
```

When I want to present the above classes in class diagram I can do it like this:

[image]

Where I can present that class `B` has a field of class `A` either by marking it with a line ended with a rhombus (**`1`** in the picture) or by specifying class's field (**`2`** in the picture). However, using both seems redundant. When should I use the former, when the latter? Is there any case when I should use both?

Edit: Actually  **`1`** could either be aggregation or composition. Although, the concrete line type isn't important to my question, IMO.

Edit2: I've found a more or less real-life example of diagram where this situation occurs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#mediaviewer/File:Decorator_UML_class_diagram.svg Class `Decorator` contains a field of type `Component`.

Comment: @EmmadKareem I'm sorry, what is "FK"? Also what inheritance? I really don't know what you have in mind.

Comment: @EmmadKareem What is an "attribute"? Also, see the 2nd update to my post. Maybe it will help some way.

Comment: I meant to use the term Property (attribute is sometimes used instead) - The link you have shown is an inheritance association, such an association may cause the child class to inherit several properties and methods.

Comment: @EmmadKareem By "property" do you mean "field"? Anyway, in **my** example I don't have any inheritance or repeating of any fields; class `A` is empty, class `B` doesn't inherit from any other class and has a single field of type `B`. It's really simple. As for the Decorator example it inherits only methods (interface) but that's not imporant to my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule in UML,
but there are best practices.

[UML Best Practice: Attribute or Association](http://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/) says about that

> Use Associations for Classes and Attributes for DataTypes